# Better Way To Handle SharedPreferences Changes

Tags: android

I have a project that has two activities (MainActivity and CustomPreferenceActivity). I have some code that when a button is clicked, it launches the CustomPreferenceActivity. Depending on the choices made on the CustomPreferenceActivity, the font color of a TextView will change. However, I don't like my solution to the problem (tying into the onResume to update the UI). Any other suggestions? Thanks in advance.

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private int colorResId;
private int fontSize;
private OnClickListener buttonListener = getButtonListener();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.preferenceButton);
    button.setOnClickListener(buttonListener);


}

@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    updateUiBasedOnPreferences();
}

private void updateUiBasedOnPreferences()
{
    SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String colorPreference = pref.getString("colorPreference", "default");

    colorResId = convertStringToColorResId(colorPreference);
    fontSize = pref.getInt("fontSize", 24);

    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setTextColor(colorResId);
    textView.setTextSize(fontSize);

}
private int convertStringToColorResId(String input)
{
    if (input.equals("GREEN"))
        return Color.GREEN;
    else if (input.equals("RED"))
        return Color.RED;
    else if (input.equals("BLUE"))
        return Color.BLUE;
    else
        return Color.BLACK;
}

private OnClickListener getButtonListener()
{
    return new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CustomPreferencesActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    };
}
```

CustomPreferencesActivity

```
public class CustomPreferencesActivity extends PreferenceActivity implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener 
{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    pref.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key)
{
    Preference pref = findPreference(key);
    pref.setSummary(sharedPreferences.getString(key, ""));
}
}
```

Comment: I dont understand your question anyway just look at this for sharedpreferences http://rajeshvijayakumar.blogspot.in/2013/03/shared-preferences-example-in-android.html

Comment: It is not very much clear that what you actually want to achieve.. Could you please elaborate your use case?

Comment: I wanted to know if there was a "cleaner" solution that what I have now. It does work, but I don't like that I had to override onResume on MainActivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have your preference activity pass an `Intent` containing the color information back to your main activity by using `startActivityForResult(Intent, int)` instead of using just `startActivity(Intent)` in your main activity.  The intent data can then be read during `onActivityResult(int, int, Intent)`, which is called automatically when the preference activity finishes.  The code would look like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // ...

    public static final int TEXT_COLOR_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

    private OnClickListener getButtonListener() {
        return new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CustomPreferencesActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult (intent, TEXT_COLOR_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if ((requestCode == TEXT_COLOR_REQUEST_CODE) && (resultCode == RESULT_OK)) {
            // Extract color information from data and update UI.
            updateUI(data);
        }
    }
}
```

When the color changes within your preference activity, you would add this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("key", colorData);
setResult(RESULT_OK, colorData);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement one singleton class and one listener interface to make this trick.

1. OnPreferenceChangeListener, MainActivity implements this interface to update UI
2. OnPreferenceChangeHeler, hold a reference of OnPreferenceChangeListener(that is MainActivity)
3. CustomPreferencesActivity call method of OnPreferenceChangeHeler when update

Comment: The problem I have with singleton classes is that they make testing code very difficult. Also, I don't like the idea of having to shared the helper between classes. Thank you for your help.